# Upgrading an complex app from Django 1.4 up one version at a time, runserver segfaults with 1.5.12

Tags: django

I have a complex, large Django 1.4 website that I didn't keep up with Django version. I am finally getting to it and doing it one version at a time (i.e. first to 1.5, then if everything works to 1.6, and so on.)

So I read the release notes and changed my code and some dependencies so things should work with 1.5.

Running things with `runserver` in debug mode, I see that only the simplest pages work, and everything else crashes python with a segmentation fault!

Running things with `gunicorn` like I do on my production server is no better: I don't see a crash, but eventually the request times out with no data.

Reverting everything back to Django 1.4 makes things work again.

Any suggestions on how I might get more debug logs or information so I can fix this?

**EDIT just to clarify**, I don't have a Python traceback. It's not a syntax error in my python code or anything, but the actual python executable is crashing with a segmentation fault.

Comment: It's most probably some configuration issues. Please post an actual traceback and as much context as possible if you want someone to help. Hire a professional if it's too secret to post around.

Comment: I don't have a traceback. This is not a syntax error in my Python code, but actually the python process having a segmentation fault.

Comment: Do you use virtualenv and how exactly you install your requirements? Did you update system libraries recently or ever in the last couple years. I'd recommend flushing your virtualenv if you use it and recompiling everything, or otherwise reinstalling everything you have in wherever you install stuff. If setup is not very complicated, consider replicating it on a clean (possibly newer) system. It's possible that it has nothing to do with django and happens because you updated or failed to update something somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference, got this sorted out. The segmentation fault was due to the process getting to eat all of the system's memory. This was happening after Haystack tried to apply some filtering to a `SearchQuerySet`.

I had recently updated Haystack from 1.2 to 2.2. I rebuilt the index and the problem went away.